# Internal error when installing many programs in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, installer

I seem to have a bug someone where in my user profile that gives an internal error 2203 `C:\Windows\Installer\6f5285.ipi`, -2147287035

I am able to get around this by using another account and using runas, but this is awkward, and makes life difficult when I am trying to uninstall programs that are only installed for one user using control panel.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Using Windows 7, UAC is on (off still generates the same error), and I get this when trying to install many programs.

Comment: Does this only happen with your user account? Do you have another admin account that you can try? Can you use the built in administrator account to install this program?

Comment: Yes, that's why I created the other account. I can use the workaround described above, but I would like to fix the underlying problem. In addition, system restore did not fix the issue.

Comment: When exactly are you receiving this error and how are you installing the applications (script, by hand etc.)?

Comment: You said that you had another account that used the runas command to run the program using the origonal "broken" admin account. That is not the same as using a second admin account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So from what I found on the internet is that this error message can be triggered by a few situations:

**Situation 1 - NTFS Permissions issue**

It is possible that the SYSTEM security user does not have permission to all of the resources needed to install the product. ([source1](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/296056), [source2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324852))

There could also be an issue with the permission on the %temp% folder. ([source](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2000547))

**Situation 2 - User account Issue**

It is possible that there is something wrong with the local profile of the user you created. Something as simple as having the wrong environmental variables could cause a problem. If this is part of a Domain, I would check the GPO settings for this account. If not, I would backup any user data in the profile and delete it. This should rebuild the profile and hopefully give it the proper settings. ([source](http://forums.techarena.in/windows-server-help/843890.htm))

**Situation 3 - Turn off Admin Approval Mode**

In windows, Admin accounts don't operate with admin rights. You must escalate to an admin user in order to access certain protected areas. Even if you turn UAC off, this setting remains on. The only way I know of to turn this off is to go into the registry and modify the EnableLUA key.

Run Registry Editor (RegEdit) and navigate to the following registry key:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System

Locate the following REG_DWORD value:

> EnableLUA

Set the value of EnableLUA to 0.

[Source](https://superuser.com/questions/83677/disabling-uac-on-windows-7)

---

Hope this helps

Comment: With regards to:
1) So I should use ICALCS on what exactly?

2) How do I go about doing that?

3) Isn't that a security issue?

Comment: @Doltknuckle: Is there a way to use the old settings in the deleted file with the rebuilt profile?

Comment: Method 1 only states that the error shows up when there is an NTFS permission issue. You don't need to use ICALCS for anything since the source document is is about office. Right click on the folders in question and inspect the security tab. make sure that your account and the SYSTEM account has access.

Comment: Method 2 is only if you are in a domain and have GPO policies in place. From your answer it doesn't seem like you are. As for the settings, the whole point is to revert to a standard configuration. You can generally copy the profile to another folder, but to get the settings back in, you have to know what files and reg settings you need to move over.

Comment: Method 3 is a security risk. I'm not suggesting that you turn it off forever, but that you turn it off for a short period. This is a test to see if the admin approval mode is causing the problem. You'd turn it back on once you figured out what is actually causing the error.

Comment: @Doltknuckle: Tried method 3. It did not work.

Comment: Then I'd probably check the NTFS permissions and then rebuild the local profile for the user.

Comment: @Doltknuckle: How? On what folders?

Comment: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/step-by-step-how-to-set-and-troubleshoot-ntfs-permissions-in-windows-xp/1055994 <- This is a blog post I found that explains NTFS permissions. You should check all locations that this installer affects. That includes the source folder, the destination folder, the %temp% folder, and the C:\Windows\Installer folder

Comment: @Doltknuckle: I seem unable to edit the permissions for "program files (x86)" either using ICACLS CACLS or the gui provided in windows (permissions in %temp% seem to give me full control, but I am unable to verify as it gives an access is denied error when I try to change permissions). Advice?

Comment: Can you at least view the permissions? This is a protected folder that requires you to go into admin mode. You can either turn off the admin approval mode, or you can launch a windows explorer session as an admin. Find the "windows explorer" link in the start menu, right click on it and select "run as admin".

Comment: @Doltknuckle: I did that (and ran ICACLS as admin) but it did not help. I can view the permissions, but all options to change anything are disabled. I have all permissions except: Full control, delete subfolders and files, Change permissions, take ownership. These are the same permissions that the other admin account has. I have full control over %temp% (though I do still get access is denied when trying to use ICACLS to change permissions there)

Comment: then the only remaining suggestions that I have is to 1) rebuild the local profile. 2) reimage the machine. Both are "last resort" kind of options that only should be tried when all else fails. Sorry I couldn't have been of more help.

Comment: @Doltknuckle How do I do number one?

Comment: Restart the machine and log into a second admin account. Right click on "My Computer" and go to properties. Click on "Advanced system settings" on the left. In the middle of the window that opens, find the "User Profiles" section and click on "Settings". After a delay, you will see a list of all local profiles. Select the account and click on the delete button. Then log out and log into the original account. Note: make sure all of your files stored in the profile are backed up, they will be removed when you delete the profile.

Comment: @DoltKnuckle, what is stored in the profile?

Comment: @DoltKnuckle, there is a question mark there, and it will not let me copy it...

Comment: By default, the following are in the local profile: My Documents, default libraries, IE favorites, Application settings, Outlook nickname cache, and everything else in the C:\Users\<username> folder. If you don't use network drives to store your data, most users have a ton of documents in there. You can copy the C:\Users\<username> folder to an alternate location to backup everything that might be deleted.

Comment: @Doltknuckle, I cannot seem to copy it, there is a "?" there.

Comment: Are you logged in as the user you are trying to copy? Windows locks some files when you log in which makes to folder unable to be copied. You'll need to log into a different admin account to copy the files. You sometimes need to restart your system before you restart in order to release all of these files.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to throw in how I solved my Windows Installer, error 2203 issue.

All of our firm's laptops are using folder/file level encryption.

I had to remove the encryption flag on the %temp% folder.

I can now install programs on this laptop.

Comment: That is the same as situation 1 in the other answer.