# Permissions for apps in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, security

Fresh Windows 7 installation. I gave "everyone" "full control" to drive D:. When I print from Firefox to a PDF document on D: everything is peachy. If I try to do the same thing from IE9 I get a message

> You don't have permission to save in this location.
>   Contact the administrator to obtain permission.
>   blah-blah

So it's not the PDF printer driver which doesn't have permission, but IE. How can I give IE (and if possible all my applications in one go) permission to write anywhere? Read: I don't want to see that warning ever again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned off UAC (User Account Control) and the message is gone, I hope for good. :-)

To turn off UAC:

- run Regedit
- find the key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Policies/System
- find EnableLUA in the right side pane. If it doesn't exist, create it as a DWORD value
- enter a value of 0
- exit Regedit and reboot.

Or see here for four different ways to accomplish the same task: [Disabling UAC on Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/83677/disabling-uac-on-windows-7)

Comment: NP.  I'd +1 the answer, but turning off UAC is a bad idea in my opinion. :)

Comment: @techie007 - Like I commented to an answer to your linked question: UAC is useful for some people, but for many it's just a nuisance. And like I also said I've never had security problems, on 2 machines running XP, without UAC, for 10 years.

Comment: Get put in charge of a couple hundred Windows machines used by non-technical end-users, and you'll quickly find out why UAC is far from a "nuisance". ;)

Comment: That's why I say useful for some people. BTW, what's "NP"? Nondeterministic polynomial? Nurse practitioner? :-)

Comment: "No Problem". :)

Answer (score 2):

Internet Explorer is working by default in "Integrity Mode: Low" which protects your computer from malware that enters your Windows via IE.

Processes running in "Low mode" can only write to low integrity locations, such as the Temporary Internet Files\Low folder

For understanding this protection mechanism see this article: [Understanding and Working in Protected Mode Internet Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250462%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

From my point of view the PDF printer driver seems not to be compatible with Windows 7 and IE. Well developed software can handle this situation so that you can save e.g. Downloads to D:. If you are starting the PDF creation by some sort of a toolbar ypu should alternatively should try the virtual PDF printer directly via the Print menu entry. This may change the way how the PDF printer is executed and therefore the permissions/restrictions.